# PL SQL - Case When statement inside If statement?

Tags: if-statement, plsql, nested, case

I need to return a field "AMOUNT" which is calculated on 2 different columns.

Initially had this (I know I could have OR statements, but it's easier to read this way):

```
CASE WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 3
WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 3
WHEN [condition AND condition] THEN 3
ELSE 4
END AS AMOUNT
```

However, the conditions change based on the date column. So now I am looking to write a
CASE WHEN STATMENT inside an IF-ELSEIF-ELSE statement

```
IF (DATE < 01.01.2020) THEN
CASE WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
ELSE 4

ELSEIF (DATE >= 01.01.2020 AND DATE <01.07.2020) THEN
CASE WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
ELSE 4

ELSE
CASE WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 1
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 2
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
WHEN [condition] THEN 3
ELSE 4

END AS AMOUNT
```

It does not seem to work so I think there might be a syntax problem.

Comment: Are you talking about a CASE _expression_ in SQL or  a CASE _statement_ in PL/SQL - those are two very different things. (There is no IF in SQL, only in PL/SQL)

Comment: Case statement in PL/SQL

Comment: Then please show us the complete code of your procedure (or function). As written those statement don't really make sense to me (as you don't assign the result of the CASE to a variable)

Comment: you can use case within case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASE structure allows nesting. So replace the IF...ELSE with outer case:

```
case when date < date '2020-01-01' then
     case when [condition] then 1
          when [condition] then 1
          when [condition] then 1
          when [condition] then 2
          when [condition] then 2
          when [condition] then 2
          when [condition] then 3
          when [condition] then 3
          when [condition] then 3
          else 4
     end

     when date >= date '2020-01-01' and date < date '2020-01-07'
     case when [condition] then 1
          when [condition] then 1
          when [condition] then 1
          when [condition] then 2
          when [condition] then 2
          when [condition] then 2
          when [condition] then 3
          when [condition] then 3
          when [condition] then 3
          else 4
      end 
    
    else ...  ;
```

**CAUTION:** You should not use `date` as a column/variable name. While it is not a reserved word it is a data type definition. Using data type definitions as column/variable name is poor practice. Additionally I converted your implicit date strings to explicit ISO Standard. The ISO Standard is not required, but you should not relay on implicit data conversions.